# Unable to capture photos in silverlight application with dotnetcompatibility mode set to false

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I am developing an application with Microsoft Silverlight which is used to capture photo and save it into database. But my problem is when I am setting  Asp dotnetcompatibality mode to false in web.config. I am not able to capture photos using microsoft silverlilight. Whenever its set to true am able to capture and save. So my question is:
How to capture photo using Microsoft Silverlight with Aspdotnetcompatibility mode set to false?

Answer (score 0):

Without the asp.net compatibility mode, you will not have access to `HttpContext` or `HttpSession`, and you cannot authenticate users using existing Http mechanisms. (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234(v=vs.110).aspx))

This means you will have to reimplement your server-side routine. I suggest adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code and let us know what exception you are seeing.